# Creating an Advance Search for my Document library which include the ability to search free text, drop-down and Date fileds

Tags: 2013, javascript, development, web-part, advanced-search

I am working on an on-premises 2013 sharepoint farm. and i have a document library which contain many custom columns. and i want to have an advance search for this document library. the advance search should allow searching the following fields:-

1. Modified
2. ModifiedBy
3. Created
4. CreatedBy
5. Tile/Name#7. Asset id.custom site column of type number.
6. published date. custom site column of type Date.
7. Description.custom column of type multiple lines.

now usually when i want to implement advance search for my custom lists or tracking lists i always use this solution https://splistviewfilter.codeplex.com/. which work perfectly for me as it is easy to control the advance search fields and their types. so i tried adding this solution to my document library list view,then i did a search and from the first look i thought that everything worked well. but when i add a folder inside the document library and i added documents inside the folder,the search did not work as expected..as in this case the documents inside the folder will not be searched unless i click on the folder itself!! so let say i have the following structure:-

1. on the document library i directly upload a document named "Test.docx"
2. then i create a new folder named "Test",and i upload a document named "Test2.docx" inside the folder.
3. then i access the "All Document" view.
4. search for Name = "Test".
5. i will get 2 results; one document "Test.docx" + the folder "Test". but will not get the second document "Test2.docx".
6. now if i click on the folder, and then i search for name = "Test",, i will get the second document "Test2.docs".

so can anyone advice on these 2 points please:-

1. can i force the advance search to search for files under folders?
2. if modifying this 3rd party solution will not be possible/feasible to solve this issue.. is there other 3rd party tools or a pure development approach i can follow to have an advance search for my document library ? such as using pure html + javascript + REST API appraoch?.

now the managed metadata and filtering will not work 100%  in my case, because i can not include fields such as multiple line of text (Description field in my case) or custom date fields (published date in my case )??